# tfds split throwing AssertionError in python 3 and tensorflow 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

This following code works when I switch my runtime to python 2. But in python 3 it gives me an error.

```
test, train = tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit([1, 8])

train_set_raw = tfds.load("tf_flowers", split=train, as_supervised=True)
test_set_raw = tfds.load("tf_flowers", split=test, as_supervised=True)
```

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in ()
>         1 valid_split, train_split = tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit([1, 8])
>         2 
>   ----> 3 test_set_raw = tfds.load("tf_flowers", split=train_split, as_supervised=True)
>         4 valid_set_raw = tfds.load("tf_flowers", split=valid_split, as_supervised=True)
>
> 11 frames
>   /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_datasets/core/tfrecords_reader.py
>   in _str_to_relative_instruction(spec)
>       277   res = _SUB_SPEC_RE.match(spec)
>       278   if not res:
>   --> 279     raise AssertionError('Unrecognized instruction format: %s' % spec)
>       280   unit = '%' if res.group('from_pct') or res.group('to_pct') else 'abs'
>       281   return ReadInstruction(
>
> AssertionError: Unrecognized instruction format:
>   NamedSplit('train')(tfds.percent[11:100])

Comment: Kindly provide your version installed on your machine for Python 2, 3, Tensorflow and TFDS.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below code, which can splits tfds dataset as per your requirement.

```
%tensorflow_version 2.x

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds

print(tfds.__version__)
print(tf.__version__)

(raw_test, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load(
'tf_flowers',
split=['train[:11%]', 'train[11%:100%]'],
with_info=True,
as_supervised=True)
```

Output:

```
2.1.0
2.2.0-rc3
'\nSPLIT_WEIGHTS = (8, 1)
 \nsplits = tfds.Split.TRAIN.subsplit(weighted=SPLIT_WEIGHTS)
 \n(raw_train, raw_test), metadata = tfds.load(name="tf_flowers",with_info=True,split=list(splits))\n'
```

Hope it's helps you.

Comment: @Nicky Feller, Can you please accept and upvote the answer if it answers your question. Thank You